# Any way to add two different font families to a select option?

Tags: html, css, html-select, select-options

I know you cannot put a `<span>` element within a `<option>`, but is there a way to add a unicode of a different font family within the `<option>` element? For example:

```
<select>
 <option value="email">&#xe010; Receive by email</option>
</select>
```

The `&xe010` portion of the code is a different font family from the remainder `<option>` text.

Comment: Are you needing this for a fallback, or for other purposes?

Comment: @Jack I'm not sure what you mean by "fallback".

Comment: Some not as common fonts won't support all the possible characters. I was wonder if you were using one of these fonts and wanted to change the font because of it.

Answer (score 0):

magic always done with Javascript here is a trick but it's actually useless as long as the included text isn't usable just for show =)

try this snippet [ **EDIT** *Use (+) button* or Double click on any option]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function newchild() {
    var nwchild = document.createElement('option');
    nwchild.name = "Magic";
    nwchild.textContent = "E-mail:";
    nwchild.style.border = '1px solid #dcdcdc';
    nwchild.style.borderRadius = '6px';
    nwchild.innerHTML += '<span style="position:relative;text-decoration:underline;padding-left:5px;;color:red;font-size:0.75rem;">New@E-mail.com</span>';
    return nwchild;
  }
  var slct = document.getElementById('slct');
  var bttn = $("input[type='button']");

  bttn.on('click', function() {
    slct.appendChild(newchild());
  });
  $("#slct").change(function() {
    var chld = $("#slct").children('option:selected');
   
    chld.dblclick(function() {
      slct.appendChild(newchild());
    });

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="slct" size="5" style="height:50%;width:50%;">
  <option>E-mail:</option>
  <option>Name:</option>
</select>
<input type="button" value="(+)" name="Append" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm not seeing the "New@E-mail.com" text when I run the code snippet.

Comment: @mutigerlily double click on E-mail:, to append new child

Comment: @mutigerlily added a (+) button to you =)