# Hi, is there a way to add a tag icon to an select option without having to change the text font?

Tags: html, css, fonts, xhtml, font-awesome

I am trying to add a tag icon using font awesome to an select option but to display the icon it has to have a specific font so it modifies the text and I want to keep the original font and not the icon font.
Is there any way to keep the text with the original font and showing the tag icon? Thanks
(Sorry for the English if there are any mistakes, but it is not my primary language and I used a translator)

I have tried adding the class to the option but it doesn't work, but I still need the font to show the icon

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. The question is unclear to me. I got no clue what you actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to add a tag icon and a text inside an <option>,for the icon to be displayed it has to have FontAwesome font-family which is the one I am using to display the icon,but the text next to it also modifies it,is there a way to keep the FontAwesome font in the icon but not in the text?

Comment: what do you mean with `tag icon`? you want to include an icon from font awesome? How to you implement it?

Comment: How to implement the FontAwesome "tag" icon without changing the font of the text next to it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65711362/any-way-to-add-two-different-font-families-to-a-select-option It is similar to what I want  @tacoshy